# Program type already present: org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException

Tags: android

I am programming Android and trying to send messages using http multi-part. I am getting a compilation error below.

```
Program type already present: org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Here is the relevant part of my gradle dependencies, that causes the error.

```
implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
```

How to resolve it?